# How to login on the site with JavaScript in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: watir, vk

Please help me. This what I have written
require "watir"

site_url = "http://vkontakte.ru"

ie = Watir::IE.new

ie.goto site_url

ie.text_field(:name, "email").set "disaster-ilya@mail.ru"
ie.text_field(:name, "pass").set "zothrf"

I need to login on vkontakte.ru. I don't know how to do that with Javascript.
Here the code from the main page from vkontakte.ru

Вход

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logged me in:

```
require "watir"
site_url = "http://vkontakte.ru"
ie = Watir::IE.new
ie.goto site_url
ie.text_field(:name, "email").set "disaster-ilya@mail.ru"
ie.text_field(:name, "pass").set "zothrf"
ie.link(:href, /quick_login/).click
```